# Netflix Clone Images won't show in rows

Tags: reactjs

I'm newer to coding and have been creating a Netflix clone with react.
I'm trying to create rows and fetch the images into the rows with the tmdb API.
I have fetched the data into my console but I can't get the images to render on the UI.
I know its the src={} in my  in my Row.jsx file.
Can anyone help me with fixing this please, I've tried following the documentation for tmdb and i still couldn't get it to work.
Thanks in advance :)

Row.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Row = ({ title, fetchURL }) => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(fetchURL).then((response) => {
      setMovies(response.data.results);
    });
  }, [fetchURL]);

  console.log(movies);

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="text-white font-bold md:text-xl p-4">{title}</h2>
      <div className="relative flex items-center">
        <div id={'slider'}>
          {movies?.map((item, id) => {
            <div className="w-[160px] sm:w-[200px] md:w-[240px] lg:w-[280px] inline-block cursor-pointer relative p-2">
              <img
                src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item?.backdrop_path}`}
                alt={item?.title}
              />
            </div>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Row;
```

Requests.js

```
const requests = {
  requestPopular: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${key}&language=en-US&page=1`,
  requestTopRated: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${key}&language=en-US&page=1`,
  requestTrending: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${key}&language=en-US&page=2`,
  requestHorror: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${key}&language=en-US&query=horror&page=1&include_adult=false`,
  requestUpcoming: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${key}&language=en-US&page=1`,
};

export default requests;
```

Home.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from '../components/Main';
import Row from '../components/Row';
import requests from '../Requests';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Main />
      <Row title="Up Coming" fetchURL={requests.requestUpcoming} />
      <Row title="Popular" fetchURL={requests.requestPopular} />
      <Row title="Trending" fetchURL={requests.requestTrending} />
      <Row title="Top Rated" fetchURL={requests.requestTopRated} />
      <Row title="Horror" fetchURL={requests.requestHorror} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Could you share your CSS?

Comment: Hey pigrammer Yes

Comment: Here it is                                                                                                         
tailwind base;
tailwind components;
tailwind utilities;

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

Comment: the comment section wouldnt let me have the @ signs infront of the Tailwind base, components and utilities but i do have the @ signs infront of them in my code

Comment: You should first go to the chrome dev tools and verify both that the rendered IMG tag in the DOM is as you expect, and more importantly that the request for the image shows in the network pane for the image. If it does no, it means its never loaded. If its, you should check if the response came back with errors.

Comment: @AdamThomas I don't have the img tag in the DOM in the elements part of the google chrome dev tools. Why would that be? In the Network section i get a 404 undefined for it.

Comment: Can you see the API request that gets the JSON coming back? If so, can you edit the post with the response body? Sounds like maybe `item?.backdrop_path` is null for some or all items. Possibly the API provider does not guarantee this.